# .ajax issue, slows down overall performance in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance, internet-explorer

I have two .ajax calls on the same page, contacting google and flickr api.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/marcomshull/uploads?v=2&alt=json&max-results=3&callback=?',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
        // some function
    }
});
```

For some reason, even if I do nothing with the data which I receive it still seem to slow down the page, huge delay on ".animation()" and other javascript functionality.

Firefox and Chrome shown excellent results.

After page loaded and I try to make more requests to flicker page slows down for few seconds , to load the content, after which it works fine.

I have been using IE7 and IE8. 
First ajax request 6 items (~32.64KB) and Second is 10(~1.83KB). 
29 requests in total on the page - 68kb of data.

Comment: What is the size of the response from the server?

Comment: And Welcome to SO. You can use 4 spaces on the beggining of a line to make a code block. More tips on the editor's help.

Comment: What are you doing with the data from the ajax requests? How much data is involved? What version of IE?

Comment: i have been using IE7 and IE8. First ajax request 6 items and Second is 10. 29 requests - 68kb of data.

Comment: What action is initiating the AJAX call?

Comment: $(document).ready and $().click(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

IE7 and IE8 are quite old browsers in today's terms and at times if you're working with a page with lots of moving parts (jQuery animates etc.) you will definitely see a lot of slow down.  More so however in IE7.  IE8 should be semi-noticeable but nowhere near as bad as IE7.

**That being said**, have you tried entirely removing the ajax call and analyzing page performance in IE7/IE8?  I'd guess that it would be equally as bad without the call.

I had this same issue a few years back and found that I was simply trying to do to much with older technology =/.

Comment: When I delete one ajax call to youtube API overall performance is increased. But slight slow down is noticeable. When I delete both ajax requests, page works perfectly, nearly as good as in chrome. - all of the animation work fine.

Comment: Very odd, I haven't had that issue before =/.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is possible for you but if you do the ajax call after the animation is finished, it will boost the performance of the effect.

Example:

```
$('#content').animate(600, function(){
//ajax call here
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, but it's not possible in my example. But I have used similar approach and managed to get flicker requests to work smoothly with my animation (thats when their no google ajax call). Once I active other ajax call and refresh the page, it's back to normal.